# StackOverflow Error, Can someone tell me why my code is generating it?

Tags: java

I am trying to write a recursive function that would tell me if a tree is a subtree of another tree, but its giving me a stackoverflow error. I visually inspected the code, but I don't see any errors! Hence, I am here to resign to my fate. Thanks for your help.

PS: BinaryTreeNode is just a normal TreeNode
    BinaryTwinNode is just a class with two BinaryTreeNodes.
    I am using Eclipse Java

Here are codes I used to run against the methods:

```
    BinarySearchTree healthyTree = new BinarySearchTree();
    BinaryTreeNode no1 = new BinaryTreeNode(1);
    BinaryTreeNode no2 = new BinaryTreeNode(2);
    BinaryTreeNode no3 = new BinaryTreeNode(3);
    BinaryTreeNode no4 = new BinaryTreeNode(4);
    BinaryTreeNode no5 = new BinaryTreeNode(5);

    healthyTree.insert(no1);
    healthyTree.insert(no2);
    healthyTree.insert(no3);
    healthyTree.insert(no4);
    healthyTree.insert(no5);

    BinarySearchTree betterTree = new BinarySearchTree();
    betterTree.insert(no3);
    betterTree.insert(no1);
    betterTree.insert(no2);
    betterTree.insert(no4);
    betterTree.insert(no5);

   boolean tru = betterTree.isSubtree(healthyTree.root, (new BinarySearchTree(no5)).root);
```

Here are error messages:

```
 java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.util.LinkedList.addFirst(LinkedList.java:293)
at algorithim.BinarySearchTree.matchingTrees(BinarySearchTree.java:811)
at algorithim.BinarySearchTree.isSubtree(BinarySearchTree.java:784)
at algorithim.BinarySearchTree.isSubtree(BinarySearchTree.java:789)
at algorithim.BinarySearchTree.isSubtree(BinarySearchTree.java:788)
at algorithim.BinarySearchTree.isSubtree(BinarySearchTree.java:789)
at algorithim.BinarySearchTree.isSubtree(BinarySearchTree.java:789)
at algorithim.BinarySearchTree.isSubtree(BinarySearchTree.java:788)
at algorithim.BinarySearchTree.isSubtree(BinarySearchTree.java:789)
at algorithim.BinarySearchTree.isSubtree(BinarySearchTree.java:789)
at algorithim.BinarySearchTree.isSubtree(BinarySearchTree.java:788)
......
```

isSubtree, matchingTrees method details:

```
public boolean isSubtree(BinaryTreeNode originNode, BinaryTreeNode opposeNode){
    if(opposeNode == null)
        return true;

    if(originNode == null)
        return false;

    //System.out.println("its a match? "+matchingTrees(originNode, opposeNode));
    //perform work


    if(matchingTrees(originNode, opposeNode)){
        return true;
    }else{

        return isSubtree(originNode.left, opposeNode)||
        isSubtree(originNode.right, opposeNode);
    }


 }

 /**
  * return true if origin matches the differ
  * @param origin
  * @param differ
  * @return
  */
 public boolean matchingTrees(BinaryTreeNode origin, BinaryTreeNode differ){

     if(origin == null)
         return false;
     if(differ == null)
         return true;


     LinkedList<BinaryTwinNode> queue = new LinkedList<BinaryTwinNode>();
     queue.addFirst(new BinaryTwinNode(origin, differ));
     BinaryTwinNode temp;

     while(queue.isEmpty() == false){    
        temp = queue.removeLast();

        if(temp.origin.value != temp.oppose.value){
            return false;
        }

        if(temp.origin.left != null && temp.oppose.left != null){
            queue.addFirst(new BinaryTwinNode(temp.origin.left, temp.oppose.left));

        }else if(temp.origin.left == null && temp.oppose.left != null){
            return false;
        }else if(temp.origin.left != null && temp.oppose.left == null){
            return false;
        }

        if(temp.origin.right != null && temp.oppose.right != null){
            queue.addFirst(new BinaryTwinNode(temp.origin.right, temp.oppose.right));

        }else if(temp.origin.right == null && temp.oppose.right != null){
            return false;
        }else if(temp.origin.right != null && temp.oppose.right == null){
            return false;
        }
     }
     //default
     return true;
 }
```

Comment: Please post the error you are getting.

Comment: probably infinite loop, check your base case.

Comment: Surprisingly, when I switch to do this in Level Order fashion it doesn't give me the stackoverflow error. I am hoping someone would enlighten me on why it is giving me an error when I do this recursively. :(

Comment: I can think of two possibilities:  (1) Are you certain that your `originNode` really is a tree?  Your program will always throw a StackOverflowError if any of the given nodes are connected in a cycle.  (2) If it really _is_ a tree, then probably the tree is just too deep for the amount of stack that you have allocated.  Try allocating more stack space.  (e.g., `java -Xss ...`)

Comment: a StackOverflow question on StackOverflow....its too meta for me

Comment: Solution, found. As it turns out I encoded my testcase wrong. Never would have expected it. The links between those no1, no2, no3... got muddled up while I inserted them into each two separate trees. Hence, it caused an infinite loop. :(